# Description for text

Tags: footnotes, superscripts

How do I do add superscript[1] and add description at the end of the page? Is there any easy way?

---

[1] Adding description below the page and using numbers as superscripts

Answer (score 6):

What you need is a `\footnote`.

Comment: more specific, write in the text \footnote{Text I want to have at the bottom}. If you are struggeling with basic LaTeX commands, have a look at an introduction such as l2short.pdf

Comment: [lshort](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If bonzi wants the footnote marker to be enclosed inside square brackets (which is unusual), then a redefinition of `\@makefnmark` will be necessary

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Some test footnote}

\end{document}
```